# Error selecting geography coordinate in Azure ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

An ASP.net webform on an Azure website selects from a table containing a geography field.  This field causes an error "DataReader.GetFieldType(0) returned null."  Here is the SQL to create the table and the code from the .ASPX.CS file.

SQL to Create a Test Table [T]:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [P] [geography] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO T (P) VALUES (geography::Point(51.4618933852762, -0.926690306514502, 4326));
```

Test.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionStr = "Server=tcp:Server1,1433;Database=DB;User ID=User1;Password=Password1;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=5;";
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr);
        Connection.Open();

        //string SQL = "SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(100), P) P FROM T";
        string SQL = "SELECT P FROM T";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Connection);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        Connection.Close();
        Response.Write(dt.Rows[0]["P"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do you have [SqlServerTypes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/) added to your project?  This is required in order for your project to "understand" the geography data type.
**UPDATE:**  Detailed instructions [here](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/spatial-applications-in-windows-azure-redux-including-denali/).

Second, if you're trying to retrieve lat/long from the geography field, you'll need to query it as a Point:

```
SELECT P.Lat, P.Long FROM T
```

Comment: No.  I have it added to packages.config and in the bin folder and it still doesn't handle it.  I may be able to get it as an array of byte and convert it to a string.  Locally it returns fine as a hex string.  ex. 0x1AB3A21223....

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to detailed instructions for installing SqlServerTypes.

Comment: And another alternative is to change your SQL query to return a string by using STAsText().  SELECT P.STAsText() FROM T.  Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933970.aspx

Comment: I will mark this as the Answer but I still can't get SqlServerTypes working on an Azure website.  I had to use STAsText() to get things to work right.  Azure is still so new that SQL and ASP.NET websites aren't exactly the same as a self hosted solution.  Also of note is that this site is FTP'ed in and not published through Visual Studio so things are a bit different than all the instructions out there.

Comment: Well Azure is 5 years old, I wouldn't exactly consider it "so new". There are differences between SQL Azure and SQL Server proper but I don't think any regarding what you need to do with Geography. I'd be curious to know why you deploy via FTP and not publish with VS although that should not make any difference as far as the final bits that end up on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use SqlServerTypes be sure to pull it into your solution via it's NuGet package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/), and be aware it includes both 32- and 64-bit versions, be sure you are using the same version as your website in Azure is using (instructions can be found in the package's readme.htm file).

You also likely need to consider the following, taken from readme.htm:

> **Action required to load native assemblies**
>
> To deploy an application
>   that uses spatial data types to a machine that does not have 'System
>   CLR Types for SQL Server' installed you also need to deploy the native
>   assembly SqlServerSpatial110.dll. Both x86 (32 bit) and x64 (64 bit)
>   versions of this assembly have been added to your project under the
>   SqlServerTypes\x86 and SqlServerTypes\x64 subdirectories. The native
>   assembly msvcr100.dll is also included in case the C++ runtime is not
>   installed.
>
> You need to add code to load the correct one of these assemblies at
>   runtime (depending on the current architecture).
>
> ASP.NET applications For ASP.NET applications, add the following line
>   of code to the Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs:
>
> ```
> SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
> ```
>
> Desktop applications For desktop applications, add the following line
>   of code to run before any spatial operations are performed:
>
> ```
> SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
> ```